# Powershell Compare csv headers with sql table column and insert data in table

Tags: sql-server, powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

#### Hello Folks

I have a problem with PowerShell scripting I didn't do PowerShell scripting before.

As you can see my question how I can compare sql table column name to csv header and insert data from csv only of matched column

This is because my csv file comes with same or different columns with there positions while sql table columns are static.

I'm giving the my attempt with psedocode

I'm not able to do it in powershell due to lack of knowledge

```
$csvfile='E:\ReadCSV\abc.csv'
$sqlTable='MEStable'
$DataSource='DESK20-RN\SQLEXPRESS'
$DataBase='MES'

$ConnectionString ='Data Source={0}; Database={1}; Trusted_Connection=True;' -f $DataSource,$DataBase
$headers = @()
$sqlcol = @()
$data = @{}

if($ConnectionString){

    # Get table column name in array
    $QueryResult = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DataSource -Database $DataBase -Query "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME=$sqlTable;"
    $NewResults = $QueryResult | Select-object -ExpandProperty COLUMN_NAME

    # Need logic here to import csv and add into hash table
    # like headers are keys and respective header value in values
    # then compare headers with above $sqlcol array and push matched header data into separate header array
    # then SQL bulk insert method insert all matched csv data into matched SQL table column name.    

}
else{
    Write-Host "Error connecting to database"
}
```

Sql table query

```
Create Database MES;
use MES;
drop table if exists MEStable;
Create table MEStable
(
    AutoId          int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    Employee_id     varchar(20) not null,
    First_Name      varchar(20) not null,
    Last_Name       varchar(20) not null,
    Shift           varchar(20) not null,
    Day             int null,
    Night           int null
);
```

Sample csv file

```
id,fname,lname,shift,day,night
1,ert,sdf,08/21/2017 Day,2,-
2,wer,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,1
3,rty,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
4,yui,adsf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
5,qwe,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
6,ret,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
7,chh,asdf,08/21/2017 Day,-,-
8,sdf,cxvv,08/21/2017 Day,1,-
```

Comment: Why are you retrieving the column names from the db schema if you know them already (you just included the DDL in the question)? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for your comment first. What I like to do is dump correct data in table column by matching headers of CSV because every time my csv files headers are changed with their postion. So in a script, I need ensure that correct data going in correct column of a table.

Comment: Both the CSV and the subsequent SQL INSERT's can be done completely by name (not position), just use `Import-Csv` to import the csv file